# Why npm creates a file with syntax error inside?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm installing dependencies for React app with `npm i` and I'm getting:

```
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 538, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     options.duplicate_basename_check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 130, in Load
npm ERR!     params['parallel'], params['root_targets'])
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2783, in Load
npm ERR!     variables, includes, depth, check, True)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 399, in LoadTargetBuildFile
npm ERR!     includes, True, check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 271, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     aux_data, includes, check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 308, in LoadBuildFileIncludesIntoDict
npm ERR!     LoadOneBuildFile(include, data, aux_data, None, False, check),
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 251, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     None)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/.node-gyp/20.0.0/include/node/common.gypi", line 1
npm ERR!     erate ',
npm ERR!            ^
npm ERR! SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:511:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.19.0-46-generic
```

When I looked into the `common.gypi` file I found a file that starts with
a half sentence / code. No wonder why it throws the error.

Why the package manager creates a file with syntax error in it ?
How can I troubleshoot this ?